# Is it possible to capture certain links from a webpage and put them in a regex to be ignored?

Tags: python, string

I want to count how many internal links a group of articles have – but I need to ignore some of them, that are listed in a category tag.

Right now, I can count how many internal links in each article.

```
links_bs4 = ['page1', 'page2']
data = []
pattern = re.compile("https://example.com/")
links = []

for item in links_bs4:
  page = requests.get(item)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  title = soup.find('title')

  body_text = soup.find('div', class_='article-body')
  link_temp = [link.get('href') for link in corpo_do_texto.find_all('a', href=pattern)]

  data.append({'title': title.string, 'count links': len(link_temp)})
  links.extend(link_temp)
```

But I need to capture some links inside a tag:

```
categorys = []
categorys.append(soup.find('div', class_='category'))
```

And put it inside my pattern to be ignored too. So my pattern would be something like: `pattern = re.compile("https://example.com/ and https://example.com/category_1 and https://example.com/category_2")`

I know my example above is wrong. How do I achieve that?

So, in a page that have the following links: `https://example.com/, https://example.com/category_1, https://example.com/category_2, https://example.com/page_1, https://example.com/page_2`

I would catch only `https://example.com/page_1, https://example.com/page_2` and then count them.

Comment: Please show some sample input strings and the desired results

Comment: how about filtering your `link_temp` before appending to your data.... so there would be no change in getting all the data, but one line simple python code comparing all items of a list to the list with ignored patterns

Comment: @Kendle I updated the post with more details. Hope it's more clear now

Comment: @Rabinzel sounds good. I'm a begginer, so I'm searching how to do that. If you have any tips, I'll appreciate it

Comment: For composing regular expressions it is always a good idea to use [RegExr](https://regexr.com/). Things you probably need for your expression is "|" for logical `OR` or a positive lookahed "(?=someword)" to have a logical `AND` and last but not least "^" for `NOT`.
But as @Rabinzel pointed out a simple white- or blacklist approach might be the easier option depending on how complex or rule-based you choose the URLs that you want/ not want.

Comment: I think Regex would be also a good approach, but for now the easier way is just to filter it afterwards. `result = [i for i in link_temp if not any(x in i for x in ignored_links)]` is the code you can insert after the line `link_temp`. This will filter all elements in the link_temp list if the element contains any substring of the list `ignored_links`

Comment: @Rabinzel Hey man, It worked as I expected! Maybe you can post this answer to my post so I can accept as solved

Comment: glad i could help! I added my approach as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For filtering the list of all the links in `link_temp` before adding to `data` you can just add this line of code:

```
filtered_links = [i for i in link_temp if not any(x in i for x in ignored_links)]
```

where `ignored_links` should be a list with all the words/links you don't want to catch.